# How to find Historical Sources for prominent person in 15th Century England?

Tags: england, 15th-century, historical-context

Can anyone suggest historical sources I may use to find out about Elizabeth Bedelgate/Bedlisgate who was the mother of Richard Woodville/Wydeville, 1st Earl Rivers?

I can find some basic facts on other people's family trees but there are no source references and I am always cautious about using family trees which are not backed up by fact.

Comment: On Wikipedia the page on [**Richard Woodville**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Woodville,_1st_Earl_Rivers#Ancestry) has a reference to her on [**thepeerage.com**](http://www.thepeerage.com/p348.htm#i3475) but nothing else that I could find quickly.

Answer (score 5):

When you have someone of this kind (Dukes, Duchesses. Earls, Knights....)  in your tree then the books **Burke’s Peerage, Baronetage and Knightage** and **Dictionary of National Biography** are good places to start.  They are expensive but you will quite often find a copy in the reference section of your local main library. Burke's Peerage have a searchable website at **[this address](http://www.burkespeerage.com/)** where you can do a free search but you have to subscribe to view the pages found.

There is another site which is totally free though which may help and that is **http://www.thepeerage.com/**  The site is not linked at all to Burke's Peerage but this website is

> the result of around fourteen years of work by one (somewhat
>   eccentric) person collecting information on the European royal
>   families and on the British Peerage, and then entering it into a range
>   of various genealogy programs

The front page of the wbsite does point out that this site is very much still a work in progress, and is bound to have a more than a few errors. You need to pay attention to any citations given when evaluating the quality and accuracy of this data.

For example, a search for Richard Wydeville comes up with

> ### Richard
>   Wydevill, 1st Earl Rivers
>
> M, #102911, b. circa 1405, d. 12 August
>   1469
> Richard Wydevill, 1st Earl Rivers was born circa 1405.<sup>2</sup> He was the son of Richard Wydevill and Joan Bedlisgate. He
>   married Jacquetta
>   de Luxembourg,
>   daughter of Pierre
>   I de Luxembourg, Comte de St. Pol,
>   Brienne et Conservan and Margherita del Balzo, between 16 September 1435 and 23 March
>   1436.<sup>2</sup> He died on 12 August 1469 executed.<sup>2</sup>
> He was
>   also known as Richard Woodville.<sup>3</sup>
>   He gained the title of  *1st Earl Rivers* in 1466.
>
> #### Children of Richard Wydevill, 1st Earl Rivers and Jacquetta de Luxembourg
>
> - Sir Edward Woodville<sup>2</sup> d. 1488
> - Richard Woodville, 3rd Earl
>     Rivers<sup>2</sup> d. 1491
> - Thomas Woodville<sup>4</sup>
> - John Woodville<sup>4</sup>
> - Lewis Woodville<sup>4</sup>
> - Eleanor Woodville<sup>4</sup>
> - Martha Woodville<sup>4</sup>
> - Elizabeth Wydevill**+** b. c 1437, d. 8 Jun
>     1492
> - Lady Anne Woodville**+**<sup>5</sup> b. c 1438, d. 30 Jul 1489
> - Margaret Woodville**+**<sup>2</sup> b. c 1439, d. b 6 Mar 1490/91
> - Anthony Woodville, 2nd Earl
>     Rivers**+**<sup>2</sup> b. bt 1440 - 1442, d. 26 Jun 1483
> - Katherine
>     Woodville**+**<sup>6</sup> b. c 1442, d. b 1513
> - Mary Wydeville**+**<sup>2</sup> b. c 1443, d. b 1481
> - Sir John Woodville<sup>7</sup> b. c 1445, d. 12 Aug 1469
> - Jacquetta Woodville**+**<sup>2</sup> b. 1444/45, d. 1509
> - Lionel Woodville<sup>2</sup>
>     b. c 1446, d. 1484
>
> #### Citations
>
> 1. [S6] G.E. Cokayne; with Vicary Gibbs, H.A.
>      Doubleday, Geoffrey H. White, Duncan Warrand and Lord Howard de
>      Walden, editors, *The Complete Peerage of England, Scotland,
>      Ireland, Great Britain and the United Kingdom, Extant, Extinct or
>      Dormant, new ed.*, 13 volumes in 14 (1910-1959; reprint in 6
>      volumes, Gloucester, U.K.: Alan Sutton Publishing, 2000), volume
>      XII/2, page 910. Hereinafter cited as *The Complete
>      Peerage.*
> 2. [S11]
>      Alison Weir, *Britain's Royal Families: The Complete Genealogy*
>      (London, U.K.: The Bodley Head, 1999), page 124. Hereinafter cited as
>      *Britain's Royal Families.*
> 3. [S11] Alison Weir, *Britain's Royal
>      Families*, page 138.
> 4. [S11] Alison Weir, *Britain's Royal
>      Families*, page 125.
> 5. [S11] Alison Weir, *Britain's Royal
>      Families*, page 111.
> 6. [S11] Alison Weir, *Britain's Royal
>      Families*, page 105.
> 7. [S11] Alison Weir, *Britain's Royal
>      Families*, page 108.

Each name in this record is clickable taking you that individual, many with pictures of them, and this searching comes up with more sources of information through the citations.

Where there is a **+** next to a child, that means they had children themselves.

Answer (score 4):

A search of Google Books can yield fantastic results.

[Richard de Wydeville married Elizabeth, daughter of John Beldelgate and Mary nee Beauchamp](http://books.google.com/books?id=1ysWkXKSrpIC&pg=PA584&dq=Elizabeth%20Bedelgate&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FBY-U977GIec0gGfn4DADQ&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAA):

[image]

---

In the preface of the book cited above, the author, Sir Bernard Burke, describes his source material as follows:

[image: Burke-preface page ix]

Comment: @PolyGeo I am reading this passage to say that Richard married Elizabeth, the daughter of John Bedelgate and his wife Mary (who was herself the daughter of William Beauchamp....).  In other words, the text which is in the link description does not match what is in the image snippet above.  Also, the word 'marriage' is misspelled. Am I wrong?

Comment: @JanMurphy I've now matched the link description to its content.  However, it seems to me that it does not say who the mother of Richard Woodville/Wydeville was (i.e. it appears not to answer the question).

Comment: @PolyGeo It says plainly who the mother of the 1st Earl was -- the listing is for the Earl's father http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sir_Richard_Wydeville (1385–1441) "The couple had at least two children, Sir Richard Woodville, 1st Earl Rivers (1408–1469), and Joan Woodville (1409–1462), wife of Sir William Haute (MP)."  The book cited is an authored work published 1866 so it is not a primary source nor contemporary with the people described, but it is *closer* in time to the people described by 150 years than the present day. So where did the author get the information?

Comment: @PolyGeo Is the second passage from the book, which I've added as an update to the answer, sufficient to answer the question "Can anyone suggest historical sources I may use?" We don't know which sources were used but it does list the *type* of sources that were consulted for the creation of the book.

Comment: Thanks @JanMurphy I think it is now an answer far better than the original which was link-only.  Feel free to clean up the comments on this one.  I have not, in case there is anything else you want to copy from them into the answer.